# Symfony 4 - Customizing form error messages

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a simple form on my website. The submitting and database entry works perfectly, but the problem is the error message display, I want to use two ways, not sure if they also work together.

I want to show errors messages declared in the form class file:

```
->add('firstname', TextType::class, array(
'required'  => true,
'label'     => 'Name(s)',
'attr'      => array(
    'class'  => 'form-control',
    'data-required-message' => 'Please enter patient name!'
),
'constraints' => array(
    new Constraints\NotBlank()
)))
```

AND / OR

I want to show errors that are declared in the entity class file:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",name="first_name", length=50)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */ 
protected $firstName;
```

Currently I have neither of the above, but what I'm trying to do is to get errors the following way, via the controller:

```
/**
* @Route("/patient/add", name="patient_add")
*/      
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $formOptions = array(
        'FacilityRepositoryObject'  => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Facility::class),
        'SFGuardUserObject'         => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(SFGuardUser::class)
    );
    $errors = array();
    $patientAddForm = $this->createForm(PatientForm::class, null, $formOptions);

    $patientAddForm->handleRequest($request);

    if($patientAddForm->isSubmitted()) {
        $formData = $patientAddForm->getData();

        if($patientAddForm->isValid()) {
            $this->addPatient($formData);
        } else {
            $errors = $patientAddForm->getErrors();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('patient/add.html.twig', array(
        'addForm'   => $patientAddForm->createView(),
        'errors'        => $errors;
    ));
}
```

I need 3 things please:-

- To be able to display error messages defined in the entity class file.
- To be able to display error messages defined in the form classfile.
- To fetch error messages via the controller and display them in the twig template file.

The other way I read about was the use of normalizers when you serialize the "$patientAddForm->getErrors()" method and get the output to display in the twig file but that only returns an empty array, I also read somewhere that this needs a normalizer/serializer to get the errors from it.

PLEASE HELP! :)

Regards,
Mzimhle

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you :

```
private function getErrorsFromForm(FormInterface $form)
{
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }
    foreach ($form->all() as $childForm) {
        if ($childForm instanceof FormInterface) {
            if ($childErrors = $this->getErrorsFromForm($childForm)) {
                $errors[$childForm->getName()] = $childErrors;
            }
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: When I add the above method and use it, I get the following error: Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\PatientController::getErrorsFromForm() must be an instance of App\Controller\FormInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\Form\Form given, called in C:\sites\coct.loc\patient\src\Controller\PatientController.php on line 53. Line 53 has the following: $errors = $this->getErrorsFromForm($patientAddForm);

Comment: did you import the Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface ?

Comment: what is the instance of $patientAddForm ?

Comment: In my form class file i imported this: use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;So the form is an instance of that.

Comment: This is how I defined the form class file under src/Form/ folder: class PatientForm extends AbstractType {.... }

Comment: It has this one method inside: public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) { ... }